# Passing parameters outside of the function brackets in PHP

Tags: php, parameters

Can parameters be passed like this in PHP - `getallheaders()['X-Requested-With']`? I realise that `getallheaders()` returns all headers, and that you would need to iterate all of them to check for a specific one, but the above works. Dont know why.

Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered pretty comprehensively, but for the record, this is referred to as *functional array dereferencing*, and has been in PHP since [version 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Answer (score 1):

That's not parameter passing but the `getallheaders()` function is returning an array which has the `X-Requested-With` key set.

```
function test() {
    return ['key' => 'value'];
}

echo test()['key'];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not "passing parameters outside the brackets", that's accessing a specific index of the array returned by the function. It's just shorthand for:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$headers['X-Requested-With'];
```

Which should also prove the "need to iterate all of them" statement to be based on a wrong assumption/understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The function `getallheaders()` returns an array. So `getallheaders()['X-Requested-With']` is same as

```
$headers=getallheaders();
echo $headers['X-Requested-With'];
```

or

```
$headers=getallheaders();
foreach($headers as $key => $header){
    if($key=='X-Requested-With')
        echo $header;
}
```

So in any case you are getting an array and you are printing the array values.

Answer (score 0):

`getallheaders()` [returns an associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php), so yes you can pull the value of that key in the manner described as above.

When asking if parameters can be passed like that, I am thinking that you are talking about to a function. Yes, you can pass parameters to a function without declaring a variable if that is not needed. [I would, however, do a check if the key exists.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
$headers = getallheaders();    
if(array_key_exists('X-Requested-With', $headers)) {
    echo func($headers['X-Requested-With']);
}
```

Note: above I am putting `getallheaders()` into a variable since I will be using the results of the function multiple times.